# Getting Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/var/task/client/build/index.html'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment

I have deployed my react app on Vercel. But when i run it is showing "Not Found" error on page. And in logs the error is **Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/var/task/client/build/index.html'**

Here is my index.js file code:

```
// express acts as a server
import express from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import Connection from "./database/db.js";
import DefaultData from "./default.js";
import router from "./routes/route.js";
import cors from "cors";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import { v4 as uuid} from "uuid";
import * as path from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";

// intializing

// creating server
// three arguments - port, callback function

const app = express();

dotenv.config();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use("/", router);
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;

Connection();

// const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));

// console.log(__dirname);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  

  app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(process.cwd(), 'client', 'build')))

    res.sendFile(path.join(process.cwd(), 'client', 'build', 'index.html'))
  });
}

app.listen(PORT, () =>
  console.log(`Server is running successfully on Port ${PORT}`)
);
```